# Extracting sub string from a string and replace in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, replace, set, substring

I have an `eventDescription` column which contains the following string:

```
Event info: code exchange. Response: {"access_code":"asdewsderfgtyhujikhygtrfdesaqwer","refresh_code":"asdewsderfgtyhujikhygtrfdesaqwer"}
```

And I need replace and put a mask to the codes something like this:

```
Event info: code exchange. Response: {"access_code":"asdewsderfgtyhujikhygtrfdeXXXXX","refresh_code":"asdewsderfgtyhujikhygtrfdesXXXXX"}
```

I was trying a function combining substring and replace but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What are the transformation rules?  Perhaps if you share your attempt, this would be a little clearer.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti there is no rule, I just have to mask those codes in the description, by customer request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`cross apply`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/), [`json_value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), and [`json_modify`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) are your friends here:

```sql
update tgt
set eventDescription = evt.pfx
                     + json_modify(json_modify(evt.jsn
                      ,'$.access_code' ,jsn.acc+'XXXXX') -- apply whatever transformation(s)
                      ,'$.refresh_code',jsn.ref+'XXXXX') -- you need to the values
from TheTable tgt

     -- find position that divides the prefix from the json
     cross apply (select charindex('{',tgt.eventDescription)-1) div(pos)

     -- use the above value to split into prefix and json
     cross apply (
    select left(tgt.eventDescription,div.pos)
          ,stuff(tgt.eventDescription,1,div.pos,'')) evt(pfx,jsn)

     -- get values for the two json attributes
     cross apply (
    select json_value(evt.jsn,'$.access_code')
          ,json_value(evt.jsn,'$.refresh_code')) jsn(acc,ref)

where tgt.eventDescription like '%{%'  -- only for rows matching the pattern
  and isjson(evt.jsn) = 1              -- and have valid json
;
```

Comment: I'm getting this error *Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.*

Comment: @Daymel - Evidently some of the values in that table are not formatted the same way.  You can add a `where` clause to filter out rows that don't follow the pattern. See updated answer.